# Could I communicate with server when iphone app moving to backgound?

Tags: iphone, networking, multitasking

Now I need transfer my app's save data to server when the app moving to background, but you know if I use network transferring in delegate function applicationDidEnterBackground, because we just have about five seconds after the app back to ground.

Could anyone tell me whether can use network transferring in delegate function applicationDidEnterBackground or applicationWillResignActive. Or there are some more better method?

Answer (score 3):

I would assume that you can continue using the network while being in the background. One tasks that multitasking is designed for is e.g. to allow a photo-upload to continue even if the app goes to the background.

You will need to call the following before starting the connection:

```
- (UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier)beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:(void (^)(void))handler
```

and remember the UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier to call the following when the connection has ended:

```
- (void)endBackgroundTask:(UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier)identifier
```

We use this method to continue downloading content that the user bought, while the app is in the background. The more tricky part is the ExpirationHandler, i.e. what to do if iOS terminates the app while connections are running. In our case we stop the download and resume it when the app restarts.

Comment: Yes, what you have said I have refered in the apple document. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/iphoneappprogrammingguide.pdf   And I will try to do and determine it.   Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) library and when your app will enter background you can suspend your download and resume it when you are active once again.